# Prove a linear transformation's graph subspace

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

I have been given this statement to prove:

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear if and only if its graph is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$

Here is my attempt:

I can show for one way that since the function is linear, we can take a subspace V in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and  let  W ={T(v) | v ∈ V}.

Given an $x , y ∈ W$, there are $u,v∈V$ such that $Tu = x$ and $Tv = y$. So we can say $T(u + v) = T(u) + T(v) =  x + y$ so $x + y ∈ W$.

Similarly, $aT(v) = T(av) = av ∈ W$ for all scalars $a$.

I think I have sound logic to this point, but I'm not really sure if I'm going the correct direction and if I am how am I supposed to use these facts to show the subspace of the transformation's graph is $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$? I don't really know where to start going the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Definition of a graph is $\{(x,f(x))| x\in \Bbb R^m\}$. Now prove using this definition.
One side $\Rightarrow$ is trivial. Prove other side.